# How to make MYSQL column equal to select query

Tags: mysql

sorry if it is a basic question but I am new to mysql, I have two tables one of them is for CustomerID vs address while the second is CustomerID vs transaction.

I want to add column in the second table for the address and make this column always select the address from the first table using the customer ID and write it. so that I have at the end one table have the customer ID, Transaction and the address. I read about stored functions and procedures but I can't figure away how to apply this on my case. ( I am using phpmyadmin)

Edit (I need this to be dynamically, every time a new row is added to table 2, it looks for the customer ID in table 1 and get its address and write it in table 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
table_addr (CustomerID,address)
table_trans(CustomerID,transaction)
```

so you need SQL is

```
select * from table_trans join table_addr on table_trans.CustomerID = table_addr.CustomerID;
```

is it？

Comment: thanks, but where to write the query in order to make MYSQL perform it in every insert. I mean how mysql will perform this command dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should add a column `address` into your second table which I assume it as `table2` like:

```
alter table `table2` add `address` varchar(100) default '';
-- this column's type should be as same as `address` in first table which I assume it as table1
```

Secondly, update all `address` in `table2` with `table1`'s address like:

```
update table2 inner join table1 on table2.customerId = table1.customerId
set table2.address = table1.address
```

Comment: thanks, where should I write this query to inform mysql to perform it dynamically every time a new row is inserted in the table?

Comment: Write a `trigger`, I think.